# Batch Program on a Single-Line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I have this batch program:

```
@echo off 
:b 
SET m=%m%memes 
SET /A c=c+1 
IF [%c%]==[10] SET /A c=0 
COLOR 0%c% 
echo %m% 
goto b
```

But I want to execute it in one line. I know you have `&` and `&&` for operators that can act as `;`, but they seem to struggle with functions. So if I rewrite it as something like:

`@echo off & :b SET m=%m%memes & SET /A c=c+1 & IF [%c%]==[10] SET /A c=0 & COLOR 0%c% & echo %m% & goto b`

I would have thought this would work, but if I open a cmd and paste this in nothing happens.

Is it possible to have a `:function` and use it for a single line, or does it have to be in a parentheses or something?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but; Did you mean not to put an ampersand between **:b** and **SET**?

Comment: I thought about it but I left it out because I assume the `:b` is a function statement and equivalent to an open bracket rather than a command, but I did try it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue lies with defining the label `b` and calling it on the same line.

An alternative you might consider is using a sub procedure. This will make calling your code a one line statement.

```
@echo off 

:b 
call :mySubProcedure & goto b

exit /b

:mySubProcedure 
SET m=%m%memes 
SET /A c=c+1 
IF [%c%]==[10] SET /A c=0 
COLOR 0%c% 
echo %m% 
goto:eof
```

Comment: Yeh I believe you're correct, I think the issue is with the label `:b`. Ideally for me the goal is I would like for someone to simply be able to copy and paste it as one line into their cmd.exe without executing a .bat though, easier to share memes that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I see this as nothing but a pointless exercise, the following should provide a similar experience as that which I think was intended.

```
For /L %A In (1,1,10) Do @For /L %B In (0,1,9) Do @Color 0%B&Timeout 1 1>Nul
```

The 10 would be increased if anyone was crazy enough to want this for any length of time.